# What is the syntax for Stringify in Moustache JS form field

Tags: javascript, mustache, jquery-tokeninput

```
 <input class="autocomplete" paramValue={{param_value}} aria-token-json = "{{{JSON.strigify(user_role_field)}}}">
```

Here user_role_field has array values, but I want to stringify it. This input field is in Moustache JS.The input field is TokenInput Js package and the `aria-token-json` accepts Stringify value.

The syntax I applied is not working..Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Moustache doesn't have a feature that allows you to call arbitrary JS.

You can pass a function in using [the Lambda feature](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)…

> Lambdas
>
> When the value is a callable object, such as a function or lambda, the
> object will be invoked and passed the block of text. The text passed
> is the literal block, unrendered. {{tags}} will not have been expanded
>
> - the lambda should do that on its own. In this way you can implement filters or caching.
>
> Template:
>
> ```
> {{#wrapped}}
>   {{name}} is awesome.
> {{/wrapped}}
> ```
>
> Hash:
>
> ```
> {
>   "name": "Willy",
>   "wrapped": function() {
>     return function(text, render) {
>       return "<b>" + render(text) + "</b>"
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> <b>Willy is awesome.</b>
> ```

but this looks like a situation where you should convert `user_role_field` to JSON **before** passing it to Moustache.

(Since JSON isn't HTML, when you include it use `{{` and `}}` and not the triple braces which are for dumping raw HTML source code into the document.)